# Sprite-Kit: Two different gravity vectors in one scene?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'd like to have two objects in one scene, one which is pulled downwards, and one which is pulled upwards, but I can only specify one gravity vector which is applied to all objects in the physics world.

If there is no way to do this with gravity, how do I best go about it without it?

Comment: Check out `SKFieldNode`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKFieldNode

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Now for some trial and error until I get this working.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: might want to post that as an answer. Also, if you need to support iOS 7, there's nothing stopping you from partially rolling your own physics—just enumerate through the physics bodies you're interested in and apply a constant change in velocity to each.

Comment: It was really more of a comment that pushed him in the right direction. I don't know much about SpriteKit, so I'm not sure my answer would be very good. He's welcome to post his own answer with proper SpriteKit-related details and accept it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so I ended up doing what rickster proposed: regularly applying a constant vector to my objects.

```
    var pullDown = SKAction.runBlock({self.pullBirdDown()})
    var pullUp = SKAction.runBlock({self.pullBirdUp()})
    var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.01)
    bird1.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([pullDown, wait])))
    bird2.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([pullUp, wait])))
```